# I need help with a complex weighted algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I need help with a formula/algorithm I just cant work out what I am doing or find anything on the internet.

I am not very good at mathematics I have not done it high since school so I understand if you do not want to help me.

So I have stats, these stars are a=1, b=90, c=10 D=0.7 but E=$10mm and F=75% I am just stuck with how to convert the numbers. I also want the number my formula/algorithm produces to be weighted. So say "a" has a weight of 50% in the final calculation while the other 5 have just a 10% say in the final calculation.

If you could help me I will be forever thankful!

Thanks Sam Cook.

Comment: Are you talking about a weighted average? If so, just multiply $a$ by $0.5$, everything else by $0.1$, and add the results.